# Ansible - Information from orchestration host script

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to fill a variable with the result from a script from the host on which I execute Ansible from?

Background: I have a script that returns some values, but this script uses programs which are not installed on the target host.

Should look something like this:

```
- name: "Get variable"
  local_shell: some_script.sh
  register: variable_x
```

Comment: See [this part of the ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation)

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question based on the comment from Zeitounator:

```
- shell: command /path | grep x
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  register: variable
```

This following only works, when you don't use extra options:

```
- local_action: command /path
  register: variable
```

Comment: The second option is historic and should not even be mentionned IMO. Deletegation to 127.0.0.1 is risky as it will probably use ssh instead of the local connection. Using `localhost` is usually what you want.